# Laravel Eloquent how to retrieve records for the logged in user

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a page which shows the students of the current logged in teacher. The user can type in the search and get the students based on the search.

I wrote this function :

```
public function search(){
        $q = Input::get( 'q' );
        if($q != ""){
        $students = Students::where( 'user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id )->where( 'first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'class', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'status', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->paginate (15)->setPath ('');
        $pagination = $students ->appends ( array (
                    'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
            ) );
        if (count ( $seq ) > 0)
            return view ( 'students' )->with( 'seq' , $students )->withQuery ( $q );
        }
            return view ( 'students' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
    }
```

But when the user type a search value and hit submit. All the students for all the users get displayed and not just the logged in user.

I did tried to put `auth()->user()->id` in every `orWhere` clause, but it doesn't seem to work. Where do I place this, so only the logged in user will be able to view the students that belongs to him?

Answer (score 0):

Your query checks whether `user_id` matches OR a search term matches.

You have to nest the `WHERE` constraints with a closure:

```php
$students = Students::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id )
    ->where(function($query) use($q) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('class', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
    })
    ->paginate(15)->setPath('');
```

Comment: I did tried that . but when I tried that the actual query that runs is : select count(*) as aggregate from `students` where `user_id` = ? and (`first_name` LIKE ? or `subject` LIKE ? or `class` LIKE ? or `status` LIKE ?)

Comment: It runs two queries, take a look at the second one.